# Django: Is there a way to move from a GET request to a POST request if the requested data is not found?

Tags: python, django

I am making a weather API using Django where a user calls something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/weather/<latitude>,<longitude>
```

My application is supposed to query the database and return the data if found. If the data is not present or outdated, the app will create or modify an entry by accessing a 3rd party weather API to pull relevant data.

Right now, I'm using the `get_or_create()` function within my `get` function in `views.py` to accomplish this. From what I've read, doing this is bad practice and any database modification should be done as a POST or PUT.

I'm uncertain if this is something that I can do or if I am approaching this problem in the wrong direction. My app doesn't currently do everything I said it should do, but it does create entries if they don't exist.

What I want is for my app to jump to a `POST/PUT` after determining that the entry needs to be created or updated.

**views.py**

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Process latitude and longitude coordinates from URL
    coordinates = kwargs.pop('location', None).split(",")
    latitude = coordinates[0]
    longitude = coordinates[1]

    # Retrieve the Location by latitude and longitude
    # If it doesn't exist, create an entry to generate a parent key
    location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(
        latitude=latitude,
        longitude=longitude,
        defaults={'timezone': 'default', 'last_updated': timezone.now()},
    )

    # Retrieve weather data.
    forecast = get_weather(latitude, longitude)
    currently = forecast['currently']

    # Assign location.pk to currently data
    currently['location'] = location.pk

    # Serialize and confirm validity of data.
    location_serializer = LocationSerializer(location, data=forecast)
    location_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    currently_serializer = CurrentlySerializer(data=currently)
    currently_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    location_serializer.save()
    currently_serializer.save()
    response = location_serializer.data.copy()
    response.update(currently_serializer.data)
    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach as you merely cache the content and don't really modify database state. Doing this in a GET request is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Write a usual `GET` method and check the result, if it is `not none` you can directly return the response with status 200. If `None` then call the `POST` method inside the If block, on success reply with status `201`.